# null reference object showing error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, null, zero

I have **locationid** in **candidates** table. I want to show this one in details page. If Locationid is empty means db stored 0 value. otherwise the id value is there.

when I try to display in details page, whenever id have 0 value showing following error, Even I check Null conditions too.

```
      **"object reference not set to an object"**
```

My code is,

```
 <%if (Model.LocationId != null)
      { %>
        <% if (Model.GetLocation(Model.LocationId.Value).CityId != null)
           {%>
               <%:Model.GetLocation(Model.LocationId.Value).City.Name%><%:","%>
        <% } %>
        <% if (Model.GetLocation(Model.LocationId.Value).CountryId != null)
           {%>
               <%:Model.GetLocation(Model.LocationId.Value).Country.Name%>
        <% } %>
        <% } %>
```

Please make this one as not showing error.

Comment: You can put a breakpoint in views and debug.

Comment: I put. then only i can find out the problem if 0 means it shows error. i don't get idea how zero means how to put condition?

Comment: Then GetLocation() returns null City or Country.

Comment: actually Locationid stores all locations. This Locationid comes from Locations table.

Comment: Just put a breakpoint in GetLocation method. You will probably see City and Country properties are null when id is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I check instead of `locationId!=null` to `locationid!=0`

My code is,

```
 <%if (Model.LocationId != 0)
      { %>
        <% if (Model.GetLocation(Model.LocationId.Value).CityId != null)
           {%>
               <%:Model.GetLocation(Model.LocationId.Value).City.Name%><%:","%>
        <% } %>
        <% if (Model.GetLocation(Model.LocationId.Value).CountryId != null)
           {%>
               <%:Model.GetLocation(Model.LocationId.Value).Country.Name%>
        <% } %>
        <% } %>
```

Comment: You will stil get a NullReferenceException if LocationId is null.

Comment: LocationId is not null. If null means it stores 0 in db. that's y i put this code.